# i cant change the color of a view widget inside settings on a settings button

Tags: view, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to have a view show the color of a setting option with the view set as a widget on the setting button, I can make the view change color after the preference has been created but not during.

//Part of the setting class

the error im getting is "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference"

If i stick the "View colorView = getView().findViewById(R.id.color_view);" inside a click listerner for example it works, what am i doing wrong?

```
  public static class ThemeFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        Context context;
        private int defaultColor;  // Assuming this is a class-level variable
        
        
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.theme_prefernces, rootKey);
         
            //the id of the view 
            View colorView = getView().findViewById(R.id.color_view);
            
            Preference backGroundColorPreference = findPreference("background_color_preference");
            Preference buttonColorPreference = findPreference("button_color_preference");
            Preference letterColorPreference = findPreference("letter_color_preference");


            // the  method that changes the color of the view

            SharedPreferences btColorPreference =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext());
            int btColor = btColorPreference.getInt("button_color_preference", 50);
            colorView.setBackgroundColor(btColor);

            if (backGroundColorPreference != null){

                backGroundColorPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(@NonNull Preference preference) {
                        // Handle preference click here
                        showColorPickerDialog("background_color_preference");
                        return true; // Return true if the click was handled
                    }
                });
            }
            

            if (buttonColorPreference != null) {

                buttonColorPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(@NonNull Preference preference) {
                        // Handle preference click here
                        showColorPickerDialog("button_color_preference");
                        return true; // Return true if the click was handled
                    }
                });
            }
            
            if (letterColorPreference != null) {

                letterColorPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPreferenceClick(@NonNull Preference preference) {
                        // Handle preference click here

                        showColorPickerDialog("letter_color_preference");
                        return true; // Return true if the click was handled
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        
        private void showColorPickerDialog(String pref) {
            AmbilWarnaDialog ambilWarnaDialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(requireContext(), defaultColor, new AmbilWarnaDialog.OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                    // Handle cancellation
                }
                @Override
                public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                    // Update the variable with the selected color
                    defaultColor = color;

                    // Save the selected color to SharedPreferences
                    saveColorToSettings(pref, color);
                }
            });
            ambilWarnaDialog.show();
        }
        
        private void saveColorToSettings(String pref, int color) {
            // Save the selected color to SharedPreferences
            SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putInt(pref, color); // Use the correct key
            editor.apply();

        }
    }
    
    public static class FontFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.font_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
    
    public static class ServerFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.server_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
    
    public static class DataBaseFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.database_preferences, rootKey);
        }
    }
    
    public void toolbar(){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    
}
```

//the xml of the theme_preference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        app:title="Different Color Selector">

        <Preference
            android:key="background_color_preference"
            android:title=" Main Page Background Color"
            android:summary="Change the background color"/>



        <Preference
            android:key="button_color_preference"
            android:title="Main Page Button Color"
            android:summary="Change the color of buttons"
            android:widgetLayout="@layout/button_color_layout"/>



        <Preference
            android:key="letter_color_preference"
            android:title="Main Page Writing Color"
            android:summary="Change the color of the writing"/>


    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

//the button_layout_preference

```
<!-- res/layout/button_color_layout.xml -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Add other UI elements if needed -->

    <!-- Color view -->
    <View
        android:id="@+id/color_view"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/colorButton"/>

</LinearLayout>
```